# Ignore '️' while tokenizing tweets

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, sentiment-analysis

I'm making a twitter web crawler for sentiment analysis. 
I'm following this tutorial https://marcobonzanini.com/2015/03/23/mining-twitter-data-with-python-part-4-rugby-and-term-co-occurrences/.

In this tutorial(part 3) Marco teaches how to ignore some terms using a stop variable in his algorithm. However when I start to collect the tweets and try to match the co-occurrence matrix - which contains the number of times the term x has been seen in the same tweet as the term y - tweepy is collecting this term: `'️'` . I don't know what this is in Unicode and how can I ignore.

I've tried the apostrophe, single right/left quote, and none of these seems to work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Array example: `[('Centre', '️', 2), ('ES', '️', 2), ('Ridge', '️', 2), ('Cyber', '️', 2), ('Club', '️', 2)]`

Comment: I found the solution. After putting the char in ord() function I found his unicode code, which was 65039 or u"\uFE0F". I put in the ignore array and worked!!!